# Exchanging disc drives (Xbox 360)

Tags: xbox-360

I have two Xbox 360s, one with red ring and one with a jammed disk drive.

The jammed DVDdrive is a BenQ; the other is a Toshiba.

I switched them out, putting the Toshiba in the system the BenQ was in, 
but I'm reluctant to turn it on to see if it works.

**Do I need to flash the firmware? 
Or will it work at all if they are different brands?**

If I do need to flash it, I have no idea how to do that or what I would need.

**Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated.**

Thanks!

Comment: Related question [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/9532/8366), although it goes in a different direction and has no references in either question or answers that could help with this one.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the key from the red ring drive and flash it into the working drive.

On how to do it, I can point you to [ElOtroLado](http://www.elotrolado.net/hilo_recopilacion-tutoriales-de-flasheo-actualizado-25-09-2011-lt-2-0-soon_1197021) although the tutorials are in Spanish.

Comment: Kool ill just take it to babel fish