# What's the original DVD drive type for my 360 model?

Tags: xbox-360

So a couple years ago my DVD drive on my 360 broke. Out of warranty and lacking cash I decided to find someone on craigslist to fix it. They did, for super cheap, however they replaced my drive with a non stock drive. This wasn't a problem until a booted up my 360 after a long period of gaming inactivity. I can't install the updates because it detects my non-stock drive, meaning I can't play any new games.

I've googled it, but can't figure out which stock drive I need for my particular 360 model and was wondering if anyone out there might be able to help me. Or in the very least point my in the right direction.

The relevant data:

```
MFR Date   - 2006 01 25
Serial     - 4131705 60405
Product ID - 77093441413170570405
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  While there are not any highly voted answers, this question appears to be a duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9532/replacing-an-xbox-360-dvd-drive .  Check that one out, and see if it helps at all.  Since it already has a bounty it's probably where the best answers will end up.

Comment: Nah, this isn't a duplicate. Solarbox is asking which drive to get for *his* 360, not whether or not it is legal to do so.

Comment: @Dusda Specifically, he is asking how to find out what type of drive was *originally* in the console.

Comment: Which type is it? Is it Pro, Elite, Arcade, or...?

Comment: To my knowledge it is a pro. It came with a 20gb hard-drive, so definitely not an arcade. I don't think elites existed back when I bought it.

Comment: Err, my mistake, make that a 13 or 14 gb hard-drive

Comment: @Solarbox: Thought about buying a dead one off Craigslist and scrapping it for the drive?  You might be able to get it cheap...

Comment: If you have the original drive that the person took out then it will be easy, if not it will be near impossible to figure out. I have swapped out many drives using spoofing, but without the original drive you are taking a shot in the dark. Unfourtuatley even Model to Model the drives have changed ever so slightly and if you don't get it 100% right M$ will see that you swapped drives.

Comment: Does the new DVD drive even work?  As I understand it, if you don't have a drive that's [correctly flashed to be paired with your motherboard](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/39491/2578), then you can't use *any* other drives, even if you're using exactly the right model.

Answer (score 1):

It may not help solve your root problem, but [this site](http://www.360drives.com/howto) provides guidance on determining which drive you have installed.  Apparently you can make a determination based on the shape of the drive tray.  They also have [a list of systems](http://www.360drives.com/list) with specs that others have submitted, that you may be able to cross reference to determine the original drive for your version.  There aren't many entries for your MFR date, but you might be able to get a bigger list if you can search on one of the other indexes such as lot #, which isn't in your information above.

Finally, I tracked down this list from [this forum](http://c4evaspeaks.com/forums/general-discussion/), which seems to be folks highly trained in flashing drives.  I'm not sure those are folks you want to chat with, but they might have the answer you seek.